# onClickListener causes crash when set

Tags: android, view, crash, onclicklistener

I have a custom view and I want to when I set a onClickListener I always end up crashing.

```
public class Holder extends View implements OnClickListener   {

Bitmap test;
int row=1; int column=1;
int x=0;int y=0;
private Paint paint = new Paint();
int deltaX=5; int deltaY = 3;
Canvas c;
String [][] puzzleS;
Button [] numbers;
int width, height;
String input;



/*public Holder(Context context)
{

    super(context);
    test=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(super.getResources(),R.drawable.smallball);

    SudokuGenerator gen = new SudokuGenerator();
    String puzzle= "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            ".........";
    gen.init(puzzle);

    gen.generate(3); 
    gen.outputPuzzle();
    puzzleS = gen.getStrPuzzle();
}*/

public Holder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    test=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(super.getResources(),R.drawable.smallball);

    SudokuGenerator gen = new SudokuGenerator();
    String puzzle= "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            "........."+
            ".........";
    gen.init(puzzle);
    String input="";
    gen.generate(3); 
    gen.outputPuzzle();
    puzzleS = gen.getStrPuzzle();
    numbers= new Button[9];

    numbers[0]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //numbers[0].setOnClickListener(this);
    numbers[1]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    numbers[2]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    numbers[3]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    numbers[4]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    numbers[5]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    numbers[6]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    numbers[7]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    numbers[8]=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);





}
```

Commenting the line numbers[0].setOnClickListener(this); back in causes the app to crash. Leaving it out I have no problems. I also tryed having the listener be in a separate class as well making it directly using View.onClickListenr... Here is also the main activity class and the main layout XML

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

//Holder sweet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >




    <com.bg.twist.Holder
          android:id="@+id/view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"

     android:paddingTop="285dip"
     android:weightSum="9">



        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="1" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="2" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="3" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="4" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="5" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="6" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="7" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="8" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9" 
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:text="9" 

        android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>



 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Holder` doesn't have any `Button` children, it's your `Activity` that does. Therefore your attempt to find a `Button` within the `Holder` results in `findViewById` returning `null` and thus the crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your class does not extend activity.

You can findViewById of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. Your class does not extend activity instead extends a view.

In your case findViewById returns null. You will get NullPointerException.

Extend Activity

```
 public class Holder extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Then Override onCreate.

```
  @Override.
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
       // initialize buttons. 

  }
```